# How do I execute Visual mode commands from a Vim function?

Tags: vim

I have a function which takes a string of commands to execute and makes sure `'paste'` is on before it runs them.  What I'm looking for is akin to the following:

```
vmap <silent> <C-K> :<C-U>call InPasteMode("<Plug>ReplaceVisual")<CR>
function! InPasteMode(command)
  let oldpaste = &l:paste
  try
    set paste
    execute "normal" a:command
  finally
    let &l:paste = oldpaste
  endtry
endfunction
```

but the command, `"<Plug>ReplaceVisual"`, needs to run in Visual mode, not Normal mode.

Is there a command like `:normal` which runs keystrokes in Visual mode?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`gv` restores the last visual selection.  So, something like `execute "normal gv" . a:command` should work.